# Call to a member function roles() on null Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm making user roles function in Laravel and everything has worked fine and from nowhere I have error: call to a member function roles() or null.

This is my html from where I'm sending request:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" {{ $user->hasRole('User') ? 'checked' : '' }} name="role_user"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" {{ $user->hasRole('Author') ? 'checked' : '' }} name="role_author"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" {{ $user->hasRole('Admin') ? 'checked' : '' }} name="role_admin"></td>
```

Then there are function where I'm making relationship between model User and model Role, and functions where I'm checking the roles:

```
 public function roles(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role','role_user','user_id','role_id');
    }

  public function hasAnyRole($roles){
        if(is_array($roles)){
            foreach ($roles as $role){
                if($this->hasRole($role)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }else{
            if($this->hasRole($roles)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    public function hasRole($role){
        if($this->roles->where('name',$role)->first()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And in the end the function where I'm assing new roles:

```
public function postAdminAssignRoles(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::where('email', $request['email'])->first();
        $user->roles()->detach();
        if ($request['role_user']) {
            $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'User')->first());
        }
        if ($request['role_author']) {
            $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Author')->first());
        }
        if ($request['role_admin']) {
            $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Admin')->first());
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

I have no idea why this is not working now, because everything was working fine till now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I guess error occurs in `postAdminAssignRoles` method.

Probably user with an email that you try to fetch does not exist in database and thus calling `first()` method returns null.

You might want to use `firstOrFail()` instead to clearly see that email is invalid. Or after fetching model with `first()` add `if (! $user) { ... }` and do whatever, like redirect, in case you don't want to display an error.

Comment: maybe thats the problem, the user who is sending request is in the database, but when i check `dd($user)` it give me `null`. I don't know why

Comment: The question is if `$request['email']` is in database, the user who sends the request does not matter. Or are you actually trying to change roles of logged in user?

Comment: This is same kind of admin panel where you can change roles of all users who are in the database, first i'm looping all users with foreach and I make view with all users and after that i can change roles of every user...This worked fine before..

Comment: Have you tried `dd($request['email'])` to check if it is in db?

Comment: Then it looks like `email` is not included in the request... Are you sure the form sends data correctly? You may use `$request->all()` to see what is sent