# Request user return null Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get the user which is sending the request using this code:

```
$user = User::where('email', $request['email'])->first();
```

But it returns null, even though the user is already in the database.  Any ideas?

Comment: What does `dd($request->email)` show?

Comment: User::where('email', $request->email)->first();  or you have to print $request->email to check value is coming or not

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin it show again null

Comment: @iCoders no I need the user for checking one if statement

Comment: @epowah, show your `email` form element and controller action please.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin here is the all code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358190/call-to-a-member-function-roles-on-null-laravel

Comment: @epowah, action looks ok, but I don't see form there. Your problem is `email` property is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, Just return or print or echo or anything.
  But, check with this below code and say what happened.

```
 public function mailData(Request $request){
   User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first()
};
```

I hope this will help you..

The function should be have request and the method will **POST** or **PUT** and
  If you are using **GET** means you can get email from routes.

```
public function mailData($email){
   User::where('email', $email)->first()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get user email from request you should use  `$requsest->input('email')`, after taht your code should be like this,

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();
```